# Alternative for Nested Loops in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops

I am trying to display State wise city details from MySQL database which contains huge database of approx 10millions rows. I had created the following code which is working fine. However, While displaying, it is taking huge time due to huge database in MySQL. Can anyone help me to write alternate to Nested loop as it seems nested loop is the one which is taking huge time. The purpose of this code is to display state name and its corresponding cities in UL and LI format. One Alternative seems to Paginate results Alphabetically. Any other suggestions welcome:

Here is my Code:

```
DisplayFormat:
<ul>State1
<li>City1</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City4</li>
</ul>
<ul>State2
<li>City1</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City4</li>
</ul>
<ul>State3
<li>City1</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City3</li>
<li>City4</li>
</ul>


PHP CODE:
function cityListings(){
global $conn;
$state="SELECT DISTINCT state FROM members";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$state);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $state=$row['state'];
?>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <?php echo $state; ?>
                                <?php city($state); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php }
}

function city($state){
global $conn;
$city="SELECT DISTINCT city from members WHERE state='$state'";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$city);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $city=$row['city'];
        ?>
                        <a href="city.php?city=<?php echo $city; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
                            <li style="color:blue;">
                                <?php echo $city; ?>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <?php }
}
```

Comment: as 'state' seems to be in both tables, have you looked into [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to make only *one* query ?

Comment: Have you done any researching on SO using keywords `DISTINCT on two columns` or `Group By two columns`?  Always research like mad before posting a question.  I smell a duplicate here.  And please tab your code properly.

Comment: Yes. Before dropping my question here i tried to understand MySQL doc but frankly i didn't understand much from that and hence seeking suggestions in this forum :-)

Comment: @ mickmackusa: Yes i had tried with two columns which doesn't worked for me. It always shows only one result i.e., state and does nto pull data of Cities.

Comment: just for ref: 10 million rows is not huge by any standards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SELECT+DISTINCT+on+two+columns  keep reading, there is a sea of Q&A pages that will answer this question.  Your process can be done in one query, but posting an answer is not good SO citizenship.  Please remove this question, research, then try, then post if you get stuck.  By not leveraging existing Q&A on SO, you are de-valuing SO as a resource.

Comment: @ Mitch Wheat: Agree but that's what my experience with this database now :-). While working on local host with 10000+ entries, its working pretty fine. But while working on live server, Its taking huge time to render results from MySQL.

Comment: @ mickmackusa: I had checked all those where i am unable to get what i want. My query is simple. I want to display all cities with distinct state which i am unable to do so. Hope you understood my requirement.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT state FROM members` => are you telling me that you don't use a `state` table with a Foreigner Key in `member` ? and same for `city` ? this is really bad practice, specially when you deal with 10M row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must have index in the database on field `state` for fast search. This one can accelerated you request dramatically.

Second, you can request all needed data in one request and then enumerate them. You must have indexes on fields `state` and `city` for this code or at least on `state` if you don't want to order by city name (remove city from ORDER part in this case).

```
function cityListings(){
global $conn;
$state="SELECT DISTINCT state, city FROM members ORDER BY state, city"; // select all distinct pairs (city, state)
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$state);
$prev_state = null;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $state=$row['state'];
    $city=$row['city'];

    if( $state != $prev_state ) // new state begins
    {
        if( $prev_state != null ) // close previous state block
        {
            echo( '</ul></div>' );
        }
        echo( '<div><ul>'.$state ); // begin new state block

        $prev_state = state;
    }
?>
<a href="city.php?city=<?php echo $city; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
                            <li style="color:blue;">
                                <?php echo $city; ?>
                            </li>
                        </a>
<?php
}
if( $prev_state != null ) // close last state block
{
    echo( '</ul></div>' );
}
```

Comment: I had created state wise pagination in alphabetical order to reduce load on MySQL database and since then my code is talking around 8sec's to render data from database whereas your code too more or less taking the same time to render data from database. I feel no difference in optimization after using your code. I am looking for more optimized code so as to render data more quickly. Thanks for your code :-)

Comment: To achieve high speed you must change database structure at first. For example extract state and city in separate tables and replace them in member table with id (with index of cause).

Comment: Exactly. That's what i am thinking in fact since i find no alternative. Thanks for advise. Because using complete db for the sake of state and city doesn't make sense. I will work on that. Thanks for your time :-)
I am accepting your answer since this is the possible solution i found so far :-)